# Problema con CocoaPods dice que no esta instalado, Flutter doctor

Tags: android-studio, flutter, xcode, macos, cocoapods

Actualice mi Mac a Sonoma en una instalación limpia, instale Xcode, Android Studio y Flutter, todo iba bien pero al poner flutter doctor todo esta bien, pero me puso: CocoaPods not installed, instale normal con

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

pongo otra vez flutter doctor y me dice que no esta instalado

luego intente lo siguiente

```
rvm install ruby-2.6

rvm use ruby-2.6.6

rvm --default use 2.6.6 

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

pero sigue igual, también lo intente con homebrew y lo mismo, alguien me puede ayudar, pues mis proyectos nos los puedo continuar ya que no puedo usar las librerías

Ojalá alguien me ayude,

Saludos!